# How to get current mouse cursor coordinate in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, mouse, cursor-position

How to get current mouse cursor coordinate in C#?

Comment: Position relative to? Did you need to capture the position when it is beyond your client area? Have you tried any of the existing events or shared properties, if so, which, and why did they not solve your problem?

Comment: yes. It is for the purpose of testing a GUI application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming this is windows forms application - use [Cursor.Position](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.cursor.position.aspx)