# How to calculate mouse coordinate based on resolution c#

Tags: c#

i am trying to develop a remote desktop apps with c#. so i have couple of question regarding mouse coordinate calculation based on picture box

1. suppose i have picture box and i want to capture mouse coordinate when i will move my mouse 
   on that picture box in c#?
2. if i click at location (200, 300) on my picture box. then how can i determine
   programmatically resolution of picture box and convert that (200,300) coordinate based on
   that resolution.
3. when i will send (x, y) coordinate to other machine and if that pc has resolution have like 
   1024x768 then what logic i need to use to convert (x, y) according to that pc resolution

if possible help me with small sample code for my question. thanks

Comment: Does this answer help you? http://stackoverflow.com/a/3922615/290343

Comment: _"i am trying to develop a remote desktop apps with c#"_ - [why](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43705/Remote-Desktop-using-C-NET) [reinvent](http://www.realvnc.com/) [the wheel](http://www.teamviewer.com/)? You will encounter lots of issues that have been addressed and fixed in those products. To be honest, if simple math and [manual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mousemove(v=vs.100).aspx) are a problem, how will you implement a working remote desktop application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple, the easiest way is to transform your coordinates to a normalized form (ranging from 0 to 1). Then you can use these normalized coordinates to calculate the mousePosition on another resolution. This way the devices don't need to know the other devices resolution.

So:

```
//First Normalize the clickPosition using the current resolution
//clickPos(200,300) and resolution(800,600) => normalized(0.25,0.5)
var normalized = clickPos/resolution;

//Now you can send this information to the other device
//The other device uses the normalized parameter to calculate the mouseClick with his  resolution
//normalized(0.25,0.5) and otherResolution(1280,720) => otherDeviceClickPos(320, 360)
var otherDeviceClickPos = normalized * otherResolution;
```

Comment: how to find resolution by c#. in my case resolution would be picture box height & width?

Comment: what exactly is that picture box? is it a custom thing you wrote or a wpf control (or winforms)? If it's a wpf control you can easily get the width and height from the Width and Height properties of the control. (pictureBox.Width, pictureBox.Height)

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like a trivial question, if it's something homework related, add a tag `homework`.

```
int remote_x = local_x * remote_width / local_width;
int remote_y = local_y * remote_height / local_height;
```

The dimensions of the picture box (`local_width` and `local_height`) can be determined e.g. by using `pictureBox.Width` and `pictureBox.Height`. The cursor coordinates, `local_x` and `local_y` can be requested or are part of the event data (e.g. of the `MouseMove` event).

Answer (score 0):

If you know the resolution of the remote screen and you know the size of the picture box then it's simply ratios rounded off to an integer.